# Overlay two circles in a legend of an R plot

Tags: r, plot, legend

In R, can I compose legend items as in...

[image]

I have data plotted as red dots, overlain by red or orange outer circles, where the size of these outer circles represent an attribute and the color of the outer circle represents an attribute. How can I repeat that in the legend?

[image]

So far I'm only having the legend...

```
legend("topleft",
  legend = c("elevation of centerline", "gradient", "boulders", "boulders in steps", "boulders not in steps"),    
  lty=c(1,1,0,0,0), pch=c(NA, NA, 19, 19,19), col=c("black", "gray", "red", "orange", "green"),
  pt.cex=c(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 2, 2)
)
```

I tried to give the third element a vector e.g.

```
 pch=c(NA, NA, c(19, 19), c(19,19))
```

without luck.

Comment: Anything you already tried? Ggplot can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to create the "Item A" and "Item B" symbols, you should use variations of `pt.bg` and `pt.lwd` in addition to the other `legend` arguments you are currently using (e.g. `lty`, `pch`, `col`, and `pt.cex`). Use the following example below and adjust the code to see how these parameters interact with one another:

```
x=seq(1,10,1)
y<-seq(5,50,5)
z<-rep(c(1:2),5)
df<-data.frame(x,y,z)
df$z<-factor(df$z)

plot(y~x,data=df,type="l",lty=1,lwd=1,col="grey60")
points(y~x,data=df[df$z==1,],pch=16,col="orange",cex=df$x[df$z==1])
points(y~x,data=df[df$z==1,],pch=16,col="red",cex=1)
points(y~x,data=df[df$z==2,],pch=16,col="green",cex=df$x[df$z==2])
points(y~x,data=df[df$z==2,],pch=16,col="red",cex=1)

legend("topleft",legend=c("Item A","Item B"),pch=c(21,21),col=c("green","orange"),
       pt.bg=c("red","red"),pt.lwd=c(6,6),lty=c(0,0),pt.cex=c(2,2),cex=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, that's a solution. A bit hacky, but works for this particular case! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but for reference I think it's easier to call the legend a second time to overwrite the red dots in.

```
legend("topleft",
  legend = c("elevation of centerline", "gradient", "boulders in steps", "boulders not in steps"),    
  lty=c(1,1,0,0), pch=c(NA, NA, 19,19), col=c("black", "gray", "orange", "green"),
  pt.cex=c(0.8, 0.8, 2, 2)
)


legend("topleft",
  legend = c("elevation of centerline", "gradient", "boulders in steps", "boulders not in steps"),   
  lty=c(1,1,0,0), pch=c(NA, NA, 19,19), col=c(NA, NA, "red", "red" ),
  pt.cex=c(0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8)
)
```